# jQuery Dropdown Menu goes away when mouseout

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to achive the simplest Dropdown in the world with CSS and would like to animate it a little with jQuery. But the "hover" function in jQuery makes the dropdown disappear as soon as it leaves the trigger element (ul#menu li a), so you cannot select anything from the dropdown.

You can see the code and the related problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xx2Z7/

I am trying everything and searching everywhere on the net, only to find out that many others got this problem, but none of the solutions work for me, and I am looking for the simplest and clearest code.

Thanks.

Comment: I had this problem myself, the reason why it hides is because you are leaving the mouse catcher 'ul#menu li a' and it is executing the hover (on leave) function. The a tag does not span down the whole of the drop down. There are several ways you can solve this problem, I felt the best was to use timeouts on both the a tag and the 'ul.menu'. Then when the mouse enters them, clear the timeout! The timeout only has to be a few milliseconds or so

Comment: Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/Xx2Z7/4/

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLCEW/)

Basically, I changed your js events, the animation is now controlled only by the mouseenter and mouseleave of your li element.
The li contains the submenu, so the submenu will remain visible even when you leave the area where the link is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Menus
  $('ul.menu').hide();

  $('ul#main-nav li').mouseenter(function() {
      $('ul.menu', this).animate({opacity: 'show'}, 'slow');
  });

  $('ul#main-nav li').mouseleave(function() {
       $('ul.menu', this).animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 'fast');
  });

});​
```

Comment: This will not work because the 'li' tags are hidden in the first place. There must be a catcher on the a tag, or the encapsulating li tag

Comment: Please take a look at the fiddle, is that the behavior you want?

Comment: @deantoni Please post your code in your answer, so we're not dependent on the fiddle site.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong! 'main-nav' is the encapsulating ul. :-)

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks deantoni!  It's amazing that I didn't try this one out. Thanks again… ;-)

Comment: my pleasure :) don't forget to accept the answer, and to upvote all the answers that helped you :D

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Since your submenus are children of the `li`, you just need to detect the mouse hovering over the `li` instead of the anchor (mousing over `li` children counts as mousing over the `li` itself):

```
$('ul#main-nav li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul.menu').animate({
        opacity: 'show'
    }, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul.menu').animate({
        opacity: 'hide'
    }, 'fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xx2Z7/3/

Answer (score 0):

You were triggering the hover on `<a>` so when the mouse moves out of that `<a>` the hide() triggers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Menus
    $('ul.menu').hide();

    $('ul#main-nav li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu').animate({opacity: 'show'}, 'slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu').animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 'fast');
    });

    $('ul.menu').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).show();
    });

    $('ul.menu').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```